# OUTSIDE LOOP COUNTER SEEN 0

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Their TOT and CNT are getting 0 after Loop running. My input is 5 but the result always got 0 why??  I want to input multiple times by the user. Is it possible???????

```
DECLARE 
            TOT NUMBER:=0;
            CNT NUMBER:=0;
            AVG1 NUMBER:=0;
            A NUMBER;
            B NUMBER;
            BEGIN
            A := TO_NUMBER(&INPUT_NUMBER);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('A ====='||A);
            WHILE(CNT > A)
            LOOP
            TOT := TOT+ A;
            CNT := CNT + 1;
            END LOOP;
            AVG1:= TOT/CNT;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AVERAGE ============'|| AVG1);
            END;
        /
```

Comment: You've tagged Oracle, Oracle11g and PL/SQL (which is a dialect of SQL used by Oracle) as well SQL Server here. What does SQL Server have to do with the question?

Comment: the while LOOP is never used as CNT = 0 < A(If A >=0)

Comment: The condition you wrote will never be met, because CNT is 0 and A is 5, so the loop will never run.

Answer (score 0):

`cnt` is `0` and `a` is `5` and your loop condition is `WHILE(CNT > A)` and since `0 > 5` is false then the loop will never run.

You probably want `WHILE(CNT < A)`.

```plsql
DECLARE 
  TOT  NUMBER:=0;
  CNT  NUMBER:=0;
  AVG1 NUMBER:=0;
  A    NUMBER:=TO_NUMBER(&INPUT_NUMBER);
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('A ====='||A);
  WHILE(CNT < A)
  LOOP
    TOT := TOT+ A;
    CNT := CNT + 1;
  END LOOP;
  AVG1:= TOT/CNT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AVERAGE ============'|| AVG1);
END;
/
```

However, since all you are doing is adding `A` multiple times then you will end up with `CNT := A` (or 0 if `A` is negative) and `TOTAL := CNT*A` and, for positive numbers, the average will be `A*CNT/CNT` which is simply `A` so your code could be simplified to:

```plsql
DECLARE 
  A    NUMBER:=TO_NUMBER(&INPUT_NUMBER);
  CNT  NUMBER:=GREATEST(A,0);
  TOT  NUMBER:=CNT*A;
  AVG1 NUMBER:=TOT/CNT;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('A ====='||A);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AVERAGE ============'|| AVG1);
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kwSAUg08)

---

> The input value should be inside the loop. I want input multiple times by the user.

That is impossible.

A substitution variable is processed on the SQL*Plus client and acts as if a find-replace has been performed on your code and then the updated SQL text is sent to the SQL engine on the database server without the substitution variable. The database **NEVER** sees the variables (and if it did it would not understand them) as they are entirely processed on the client side.

The SQL*Plus client does not run the code when it processes the substitution variables so it will not unroll the loops and request multiple inputs from the user; it will just replace the value once and send the updated text to the server to process.

Comment: The input value should be inside the loop. I want input multiple times by the user.

Comment: @SuyogMate Updated - you cannot do that as substitution variables are processed on the client and then the updated text, with all the variables replaced, is passed to the database server where it is executed.